# Best back off implementation for waiting threads before parking them in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

It should gracefully slowdown thread before parking it.

I tried spins, `Thread.yield()` and `LockSupport.parkNanos(1L)`:

```
  def backOff() {
    backOffs += 1
    if (backOffs <= spinCount) () // spin
    else if (backOffs <= spinCount + yieldCount) Thread.`yield`()
    else if (backOffs <= spinCount + yieldCount + parkNanosCount) LockSupport.parkNanos(1L)
    else {
      waitingThreads.add(Thread.currentThread())
      LockSupport.park(this)
      backOffs = 0
    }
  }
```

Are any other approaches?

Looking for back off implementation which is suitable for most JVMs 1.6+ on different OSs & environments.

Comment: Just a comment on the code - should you be incrementing yieldCount and parkNanosCount? and then be resetting them on park?

Comment: I think spinCount, yeildCount and parkNanosCount should be final values calculated before thread starting (because they depend on JVM, OS, etc.), and to be suitable all these back off phases should took about the same time that required to thread parking and unparking

Comment: Sorry - misread what was going on.